# How do I send user to a link upon successful xhr POST?

Tags: javascript

I have a working web page, complete with a JavaScript function that displays text messages based on the "non-successful" results, within the same page.  Everything is working except this last step.

I need to send a JSON string to my server in a POST, and regardless of outcome, I need the user's browser to navigate to the page returned in the POST. (Just as if it were an ordinary link ( href ="" type of thing.)  I am using the custom tag [OK_RESULT_URL] that my server replaces with the real URL just before the page is downloaded.

You see in my code below, that I set the URL to [OK_RESULT_URL] **AND** the window.location to [OK_RESULT_URL] as well, which seems wrong.  That means I'm making two hits to [OK_RESULT_URL], one is a POST with a body (which is correct) and the other one a GET without a body (which is wrong).

I'm a total newbie to JavaScript, so I'm probably missing something obvious.  It's as if instead of using xhr.Send() I want to say xhr.SendAndNaviateTo() ... or something like that.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
onApproval: function (response) {
        showResult("Approved", JSON.stringify(response, null, ''\t''));
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = "[OK_RESULT_URL]";
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
    window.location = "[OK_RESULT_URL]"};
  var data = JSON.stringify(response);
  xhr.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is no JS Problem, because if you send data with POST and then redirect the User to the same URL. What you are looking for is a formular which sends POST Data and shows the Result of that onsubmit. Beside that, it's very late to send the data if the response is already there

Comment: "What you are looking for is a formular which sends POST Data and shows the Result of that onsubmit." ok, how do I do that?